# Chef: Use library function in attributes

Tags: chef-infra

How can I access an own library function (created in the following module) in a cookbook's attribute file?

```rb
module Gerrit
  module Helpers
    def gerrit_above?(version)
      require 'chef/version_constraint'
      Chef::VersionConstraint.new(">= #{version}").include?(node['gerrit']['version'])
    end
  end
end

Chef::Recipe.send(:include, ::Gerrit::Helpers)
Chef::Resource.send(:include, ::Gerrit::Helpers)
Chef::Provider.send(:include, ::Gerrit::Helpers)
```

I can access it in recipes through `gerrit_above?`, but didn't find a way to make it at the same time usable in an attributes file. I tried the following line

```
Chef::Node::Attribute.send(:include, ::Gerrit::Helpers)
```

But then it fails while accessing `node` with:

```
Undefined method or attribute `node' on `node'
```

Has anyone a clean solution?

Comment: Attributes are loaded before libraries, so you really can't. What are you trying to accomplish? If you need a library to compute an attribute, that attribute it too complex imo

Comment: I want to set node attributes based on the version of the deployed application (gerrit). Would only be cosmetics, it's okay for me to also do this in the recipe. Thx

Comment: I'm generally -1 on any type of computational or compiled attributes. They _will_ cause you problems. Also, ask yourself - is this something that really should be tunable, or am I just using attributes as a global variable?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the `node.run_state` object to store transient data between resources and recipes. See more info here: https://docs.chef.io/recipes/#noderun_state

If you absolutely have to store data within attributes, create a recipe which computes and sets the attribute values and set this as the first recipe that gets executed in the default recipe.